# Javascript conditional AND not being triggered

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want to check if 9 different variables are active but the JavaScript AND conditional does not seem to work at all. There's no errors in the Console. And when I log the variables to measure against the conditional, they all return the value expected

```js
function tt(editableObj) {
  if (editableObj == "vat_certificate_done") {
    var vat_certificate_done = "Yes";
    console.log('1 vat_certificate_done:', vat_certificate_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "client_id_done") {
    var client_id_done = "Yes";
    console.log('2 client_id_done: ', client_id_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "boards_resolution_done") {
    var boards_resolution_done = "Yes";
    console.log('3 boards_resolution_done:', boards_resolution_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "signed_done") {
    var signed_done = "Yes";
    console.log('4 signed_done:', signed_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "surety_done") {
    var surety_done = "Yes";
    console.log('5 surety_done:', surety_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "bank_rating_done") {
    var bank_rating_done = "Yes";
    console.log('6 bank_rating_done:', bank_rating_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "credit_checks_done") {
    var credit_checks_done = "Yes";
    console.log('7 credit_checks_done:', credit_checks_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "trade_refs_done") {
    var trade_refs_done = "Yes";
    console.log('8 trade_refs_done:', trade_refs_done);
    ticks++;
  }
  if (editableObj == "credit_limit_done") {
    var credit_limit_done = "Yes";
    console.log('9 credit_limit_done:', credit_limit_done);
    ticks++;
  }

  if (vat_certificate_done === "Yes" && client_id_done === "Yes") {
    console.log('All Done');
    $("#tags").html("All Done");
    $("#submit_for_review").html('<input type="checkbox" value="<?PHP echo $_REQUEST['
      app_id '];?>" name="Status" id="YesNo" unchecked data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Pending" data-on="Approval" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">');
  }
```

In Google Developer's console, all 9 variables show "Yes", i.e.

- 1 vat_certificate_done: Yes
- 6 bank_rating_done: Yes
- 2 client_id_done:  Yes
- 7 credit_checks_done: Yes
- 3 boards_resolution_done: Yes
- 8 trade_refs_done: Yes
- 4 signed_done: Yes
- 9 credit_limit_done: Yes
- 5 surety_done: Yes

Why would the AND conditional not run?

Comment: Aren't triple equals signs used for boolean eval only?

Comment: Might be a better idea to use booleans rather than magic strings.

Comment: @IoCalisto - No, it's just strict equality (no coercion).

Comment: @IoCalisto triple equals is used to check if it's exact, for instance, `1=='1'` is true, but `1==='1'` would be false, the types are different

Comment: How come the same parameter `editableObj` equate against different conditionals and return true twice?

Comment: With your code, it's **impossible** for both `vat_certificate_done` and `client_id_done` to be `"Yes"`, because they're each only set to `"Yes"` within an `if` requiring that `editableObj` match **two different strings**. It can't.

Comment: if you move all the console.logs before the last if statement you'll see why, your logic only works if vat_certificate_done and client_id_done are global variables

Comment: @ChrisLi I have declared all the variables as global variables, before running the if statements. But when I move all the console.logs to just before the last if statement they all return as undefined, except for the last variable, credit_limit_done

Comment: @ChrisLi, when I move all the console.logs to after the last if statement, I see that it runs the code 3 times. In one iteration vat_certificate_done == "A", in the 2nd iteration vat_certificate_done == undefined and client_id_done == "B"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have two values with `'Yes'`, because `editableObj` can have only one value and this is checked.

Comment: please ask a new question.